# Unnecessary error in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this error in matlab editor showing

```
an end might be possibly missing matching for
```

The code runs fine though, I am not sure why it is showing this error even when everything is matching. Any idea guys why this is so and how to remove this annoying red marker?

Comment: From your question it's impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: Show us your code please

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, it's a [mlint warning](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlint.html) which should help you writing good code. In your case, the `if` and the `end` are not indented at the same level. Click on the `if` to see which `end` is matching.

Comment: I have checked my code and there is a match. If there was no match the code would not have run. The indentation is also good. I have used smart indentation. Is there any other way to get rid of this red line showing the error?

Comment: You can turn the warnings off, but I recommend not to do so.